# Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: co.antariksh.antarikshbin, PID: 15765
>                                                                              android.view.InflateException:

```
*********This is a TabActivity****************
package co.antariksh.antarikshbin;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;



public class OneActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_one);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);



    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       OneActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //placehlder deleted

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    CameraActivity cameraActivity = new CameraActivity();
                    return cameraActivity;
                case 1:
                    MaterialActivity materialActivity = new MaterialActivity();
                    return materialActivity;
                case 2:
                    DetailActivity detailActivity =  new DetailActivity();
                    return detailActivity;
                case 3:
                    MoreDetailsActivity moreDetailsActivity = new MoreDetailsActivity();
                    return moreDetailsActivity;
                case 4:
                    MapPointActivity mapPointActivity = new MapPointActivity();

                    return mapPointActivity;
                case 5:
                    AddRecordActivity addRecordActivity = new AddRecordActivity();
                    return addRecordActivity;
                default:
                    return null;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 6;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:

                    return "Take Picture";
                case 1:

                    return  "Material";
                case 2:

                    return  "Info";
                case 3:

                    return  "Details";
                case 4:

                    return  "Map";
                case 5:

                    return  "Publish";

            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}

*******This is a Fragment for the above activity**************
package co.antariksh.antarikshbin;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.ResultReceiver;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocomplete;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_CANCELED;
import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

public class MapPointActivity extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private static String TAG = "MAP LOCATION";
    Context mContext;
    TextView mLocationMarkerText;
    private LatLng mCenterLatLong;
    private AddressResultReceiver mResultReceiver;
    protected String mAddressOutput;
    protected String mAreaOutput;
    protected String mCityOutput;
    protected String mStateOutput;
    EditText mLocationAddress;
    TextView mLocationText;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE = 1;
    Toolbar mToolbar;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_map_point, container, false);

        mContext = getContext();
        if (mapFragment == null) {
            mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                   mapReady(googleMap);
                }
            });
        }

             // R.id.map is a FrameLayout, not a Fragment
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();

          // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
         // SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
        //        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mLocationMarkerText = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.locationMarkertext);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);



      //  mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mResultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler());

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            // If this check succeeds, proceed with normal processing.
            // Otherwise, prompt user to get valid Play Services APK.
            if (!AppUtils.isLocationEnabled(mContext)) {
                // notify user
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                dialog.setMessage("Location not enabled!");
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Open location settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Location not supported in this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return rootView;
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    public void mapReady(GoogleMap googleMap){
        Log.d(TAG, "OnMapReady");
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                Log.d("Camera postion change" + "", cameraPosition + "");
                mCenterLatLong = cameraPosition.target;


                mMap.clear();

                try {

                    Location mLocation = new Location("");
                    mLocation.setLatitude(mCenterLatLong.latitude);
                    mLocation.setLongitude(mCenterLatLong.longitude);

                    startIntentService(mLocation);
                    mLocationMarkerText.setText("Lat : " + mCenterLatLong.latitude + "," + "Long : " + mCenterLatLong.longitude);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
//        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
//        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
//
//        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
//        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
//        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
//        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            changeMap(mLastLocation);
            Log.d(TAG, "ON connected");

        } else
            try {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                        mGoogleApiClient, this);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        try {
            if (location != null)
                changeMap(location);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }


    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        try {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, getActivity(),
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                //finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void changeMap(Location location) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Reaching map" + mMap);


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
            LatLng latLong;


            latLong = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(latLong).zoom(19f).tilt(70).build();

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            mLocationMarkerText.setText("Lat : " + location.getLatitude() + "," + "Long : " + location.getLongitude());
            startIntentService(location);


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    }


    /**
     * Receiver for data sent from FetchAddressIntentService.
     */
    class AddressResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
        public AddressResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        /**
         * Receives data sent from FetchAddressIntentService and updates the UI in MainActivity.
         */
        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {

            // Display the address string or an error message sent from the intent service.
            mAddressOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RESULT_DATA_KEY);

            mAreaOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_AREA);

            mCityOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_CITY);
            mStateOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_STREET);

            displayAddressOutput();

            // Show a toast message if an address was found.
            if (resultCode == AppUtils.LocationConstants.SUCCESS_RESULT) {
                //  showToast(getString(R.string.address_found));


            }


        }

    }

    /**
     * Updates the address in the UI.
     */
    protected void displayAddressOutput() {
        //  mLocationAddressTextView.setText(mAddressOutput);
        try {
            if (mAreaOutput != null)
                // mLocationText.setText(mAreaOutput+ "");

                mLocationAddress.setText(mAddressOutput);
            //mLocationText.setText(mAreaOutput);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an intent, adds location data to it as an extra, and starts the intent service for
     * fetching an address.
     */
    protected void startIntentService(Location mLocation) {
        // Create an intent for passing to the intent service responsible for fetching the address.
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), FetchAddressIntentService.class);

        // Pass the result receiver as an extra to the service.
        intent.putExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);

        // Pass the location data as an extra to the service.
        intent.putExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, mLocation);

        // Start the service. If the service isn't already running, it is instantiated and started
        // (creating a process for it if needed); if it is running then it remains running. The
        // service kills itself automatically once all intents are processed.
        getActivity().startService(intent);
    }


    private void openAutocompleteActivity() {
        try {
            // The autocomplete activity requires Google Play Services to be available. The intent
            // builder checks this and throws an exception if it is not the case.
            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                    .build(getActivity());
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
            // Indicates that Google Play Services is either not installed or not up to date. Prompt
            // the user to correct the issue.
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(getActivity(), e.getConnectionStatusCode(),
                    0 /* requestCode */).show();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            // Indicates that Google Play Services is not available and the problem is not easily
            // resolvable.
            String message = "Google Play Services is not available: " +
                    GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorString(e.errorCode);

            Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called after the autocomplete activity has finished to return its result.
     */
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Check that the result was from the autocomplete widget.
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the user's selected place from the Intent.
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(mContext, data);

                // TODO call location based filter


                LatLng latLong;


                latLong = place.getLatLng();

                //mLocationText.setText(place.getName() + "");

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(latLong).zoom(19f).tilt(70).build();

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


            }


        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(mContext, data);
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Indicates that the activity closed before a selection was made. For example if
            // the user pressed the back button.
        }
    }


}
```

Here is the error:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment did not create a view.

Comment: put your xml code

Comment: show xml please.

Answer (score 1):

**Change this line:**

```
mContext = getContext();
```

**To this:**

```
mContext = getActivity();
```

**Reason:**
The method `View.getContext()` runs only when a view has already been inflated so for this you have used it inside `onCreateView` while the `View` has not been made yet, until the line `return rootView;` is reached. (*Though you could use your way in other lifecycle methods like `onResume()`* after `onCreateView`).

So instead use the activity since the `Fragment` has already been attached up to this point and the `Context` is the `Activity` for this `Fragment`. If you still face `Context` issues comment below and I will edit the answer!

In addition to that Please use Class names that resemble the situation for example this part

```
public class MapPointActivity extends Fragment ....
```

It was good if you would call it `MapPointFragment` since it extends `Fragment` not `Activity`,(*its a good design*) especially for Future reference of the code.